# How to add incremental values to a css attribute with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, increment, parsefloat

Basically I have a series of DIVs with varying "top" "bottom" and "padding" values. The "bottom" and "padding" I want to 0 out or eliminate, but for the "top" I need each consecutive DIV to increase by 10px, starting with 0. So basically turn something like this:

```
<div class="someclass" style="position:absolute;top:10px;bottom:5;padding:4;"> </div>
<div class="someclass" style="position:absolute;top:15px;bottom:10;padding:2;"> </div>
<div class="someclass" style="position:absolute;top:5px;bottom:5;padding:6;"> </div>
```

INTO THIS:

```
<div class="someclass" style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0;padding:0;"> </div>
<div class="someclass" style="position:absolute;top:10px;bottom:0;padding:0;"> </div>
<div class="someclass" style="position:absolute;top:20px;bottom:0;padding:0;"> </div>
```

Not quite sure of the best way to zero out the other properties, but the biggest issue has been figuring out the incremental increases. Here's a fiddle I've been working with, but it only ads the +10 to all divs instead of incrementing. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y21rjadu/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('.someclass').each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).css({
        'top': (index * 10) + 'px',
        'bottom': 0,
        'padding': 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand expected results properly you can use the element index to increment with:

```
$('.someclass').css('top', function(i, v) {
    return i*10 ;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y21rjadu/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
 for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    x[i].style.top = (i*10) + 'px';
  };
```